# MYSQL transactions and guaranteeing inserts/deletes/updates

Tags: mysql, database-design, stored-procedures, transaction

I have a stored procedure called processWinningBet. It takes a pendingBet and does these things.

update balance table for user

creates a row in historic bets table

deletes the corresponding row in pending bet table

creates 2 entries in a ledgers table.

While writing this ( I know it's not great right now and im pretty sure I completely missed the mark with my implementation of optimistic locking but that's a different question i guess)
I ran into times where I would have 1 row updated and then the other inserts and deletes would not happen. I thought transactions prevented this. I thought that if you had say 4 inserts wrapped in a transaction you would have 4 inserts or no inserts.

How do I absolutely guarantee I have 3 inserts, 1 update, and 1 delete happen, or all of it is rolled back?

I think I'm misunderstanding how transactions work and i need some of my own error handling? Would something like this be typical to make sure everything happens?

```
START TRANSACTION;
update
IF (SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 1 ) THEN
    delete
        IF (SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 1 ) THEN
            insert
                IF (SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 1 ) THEN
                    insert
                        IF (SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 1 ) THEN
                            insert
                                IF (SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 1 ) THEN
                                    COMMIT
                                ELSE ROLLBACK
                        ELSE ROLLBACK
                ELSE ROLLBACK
        ELSE ROLLBACK
    ELSE ROLLBACK
```

here is the current stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ProcessWinningBet $$
  CREATE PROCEDURE ProcessWinningBet(
  IN pending_bet_id BIGINT,
    IN  _user_id BIGINT, 
    IN  _game_account_id BIGINT, 
    IN _amount DECIMAL(10,2),
    IN _bet_odds DECIMAL(10,2),
    IN _fee_percentage DECIMAL(10,2),
    IN _fee_amount DECIMAL(10,2),
    IN _user_has_reported BOOLEAN,
    IN _user_reported_result VARCHAR(40),
    IN _user_notes VARCHAR(400),
    IN _bet_created_date DATETIME,
    IN _user_reported_date DATETIME,
    IN _manager_id BIGINT,
    IN _manager_reported_result VARCHAR(40),
    IN _manager_notes VARCHAR(400)
    )
BEGIN
     DECLARE _old_version BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE _user_balance_before_fee DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE _user_balance_after_fee DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE _historic_bet_id BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
     

    SELECT id, user_id, balance, (available_balance + _amount + _amount -_fee_amount) AS new_available_balance,
    (balance + _amount -_fee_amount) AS new_balance ,
    version  INTO @id,@user_id, @balance, @new_available_balance, @new_balance, @_old_version 
       FROM balances
       WHERE user_id = _user_id;
       
       
       SET _old_version = @_old_version;
       SET _user_balance_before_fee = @new_balance;
       SET _user_balance_after_fee = @new_balance - _fee_amount;
       
       
       
       START TRANSACTION;
        
       UPDATE balances
       SET available_balance = @new_available_balance, balance = @new_balance, modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
           version = version + 1
       WHERE user_id = _user_id
           AND version = _old_version;
           
        

    IF (SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 1 ) THEN
     INSERT INTO historic_bets (user_id, game_account_id, amount, bet_odds, fee_percentage, fee_amount,user_has_reported, user_reported_result, user_notes, bet_created_date, user_reported_date, manager_id, manager_reported_result, manager_notes)
        VALUES (_user_id, _game_account_id, _amount, _bet_odds, _fee_percentage, _fee_amount,_user_has_reported, _user_reported_result, _user_notes, _bet_created_date, _user_reported_date, _manager_id, _manager_reported_result, _manager_notes);
    
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as historic_bet_id INTO @historic_bet_id LIMIT 1;
    SET _historic_bet_id = @historic_bet_id;
    
    call log_msg(concat('_historic_bet_id is: ', _historic_bet_id, ' and _user_balance_after_fee is: ', _user_balance_after_fee));
    
    
    DELETE FROM pending_bets WHERE id=pending_bet_id;
    
    INSERT INTO ledger (user_id, game_account_id, credit_user_id, debit_user_id, amount, reason , user_balance_result,   historic_bet_id, manager_id, manager_reported_result, manager_notes)
        VALUES (_user_id, _game_account_id, 77777777, _user_id, _fee_amount, "Fee For Bet Win",  _user_balance_after_fee,   _historic_bet_id, _manager_id, _manager_reported_result, _manager_notes);
    
    INSERT INTO ledger (user_id, game_account_id, credit_user_id, debit_user_id, amount, reason , user_balance_result,   historic_bet_id, manager_id, manager_reported_result, manager_notes)
        VALUES (_user_id, _game_account_id, _user_id, 77777777, _amount, "Bet Win",  _user_balance_before_fee,   _historic_bet_id, _manager_id, _manager_reported_result, _manager_notes);
        
           
    
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
END$$
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `SELECT` should be *inside* the transaction and with `FOR UPDATE` on the end:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE balances ...;
IF ... THEN ROLLBACK; RETURN; END IF;
...
COMMIT;
```